# can locks prevent unrepeatable reads?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, rdbms, database

I have a particular question in my mind for some moment, let's say I have a schedule like this:

S2(A), R2(A), U2(A), X1(A), W1(A), Commit1(A), U1(A), S2(A), R2(A), U2(A)

- S is share lock, X is exclusive lock, U is unlock either share lock or exclusive lock.

Even if I have shared lock and exclusive lock here, I still get different value of A in transaction 2, which happens at the very beginning and ending - since transaction 1 changes value of A in the middle.

In this case, does that mean locks cannot prevent unrepeatable reads at all?

Comment: What database platform?

Comment: Either I don't understand what you mean by your schedule or locks or you have something wrong: a shared lock on A for 2 means: a) 1 cannot get an exclusive lock on A and b) 1 cannot modify A. Your shedule (if it means the execution order, not the request order) violates both. And of course locks can prevent unrepeatable reads. Proof: at least one existing database system supports the "Repeatable Read" isolation level.

Comment: @Solarflare I have added U for unlock above, please take a look. The schedule means 2 reads A first, then 1 changes A to some other value, after that 2 reads A again. Since 2 reads two different As, it should be unrepeatable read, and lock does not prevent it

Comment: So what you are saying is: if you intentionally do something that will allow unrepeatable read (unlocking the lock that is there to prevent unrepeatable reads), you can get unrepeatable read. Yes. That is 100% true. Still doesn't mean (correctly used) locks cannot prevent unrepeatable reads though.

Comment: It looks like you haven't actually asked whatever question you really want to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Slocks** locks the value of A and wont allow you to set an **Xlock** so you cant write the new value of **A** unless you reamove the **Slock** is removed.

and **Xlocks** won't allow both  reading  and writing the value of **A** unless its removed.